# API security on private and public side

Tags: api, security, oauth, saml

First of all i wanna apoligise for my bad english, iam from holland.

For an school internship i read the last days a lot about API's and watched a lot of video's. But the security options are not clear for me. I read somethin about Oauth, saml and openID but i dont know which i can use in my situation.

[image]

This is the situation i will create. i need to add 2 security's. one for the private(internal) side and one for the public side.

**Private(internal) side**

For the private side i cant find any solution. I think i can use oauth for it . but i cant find which flows there are and also webflow) dont know which flow i need to use. [This one is what i mean (youtube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0PvQcLzVGF0) i also read topics on stackoverflow but i cant find a clear answer on this question.

The backend on the private side wil never change and there wil never be more api gateways or backends on the private side. No-one need to be acces to the backend, only the API gateway.

**Public side**

On the public side there are a lot kinds of clients but they dont need to login with credentials. I only wanna know which application uses our API and how many connections they make. I will be able to disable the acces from one client. Also here i came out by oauth. but the flow i found works witch user credentials but i don't need to identify each infividualy user.

Can some help me to find a good or best practice security method for my situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to care about OAuth. It is enough to (1) issue a pair of API key and API secret (= API credentials) to each client application and (2) require that API calls to your Web APIs come along with API credentials.

OAuth is required only when your web service has end-users and you want to allow third-party client applications to access the end-users' data with restricted privileges.

Comment: Thanks, i read a lot more about oauth and now i understand your answer